# Where can I get experimental versions of dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

Where can i get hold of the experimental versions of Dropbox for Ubuntu?

Im looking for a version that allows the tray icons to be modified, and as far as im aware this functionality is only available in the latest versions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can drop last experimental build from [Dropbox Forum](http://forums.dropbox.com/), [here](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=26476&replies=9) you can find the last version available, 0.8.110.

Simply download your desired tar.gz and extract `.dropbox-dist` into your Home folder, than copy your desired icons in `/home/yourname/.dropbox-dist/icons/hicolor/16x16/status`. Be careful to icons name.

Comment: is it best to remove my existing install before install the new one?

Comment: You can just overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Thanks to @skalka, ive spotted the difference between the dropbox daemon, and the `dropbox-nautilus` application that shows up in the package manager.

There is a script on the dropbox forum for an app that will automatically pull the dropbox daemon up the latest version:

http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=12153